# Tufte-latex: Margin references are too verbose

Tags: bibliographies, citing, tufte, multiple-citations

I'm using `\documentclass{tufte-book}`, and I have a problem that the **side-references are too verbose**.

Sometimes when writing, it is useful to rapidly cite several works in the space of a single sentence or two sentences. `tufte-latex` places the entire bibliography entry into the margin (as well as into the bibliography section), but this can quickly fill an entire page's margin, preventing use of margin comments for other content on that page.

[image: Rendered page from minimum working example]

I would like to adjust the `tufte-latex` margin citations so they show a minimal version of the citation, but leave the full citation in the bibliography. For example, the minimal working example below includes the citation

> Quoc Phong Nguyen, Bryan Kian Hsiang Low, and Patrick Jail-let. Inverse Reinforcement Learning with Locally Consistent Reward Functions. In Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems 28, pages 1747–1755, Montréal, Quebec, Canada, 2015. Curran Associates, Inc.

A reasonable compromise would be if the margin citation listed the first author's surname, then "et al." for any future authors, then the title and year. So the above would become;

> Nguyen et al., Inverse Reinforcement Learning with Locally Consistent Reward Functions, 2015.

Interested readers could then look up the reference in the bibliography to locate the publisher, publication venue, page numbers and/or location *&c*.

---

Minimum Working Example;

```latex
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\title{Smaller tufte-latex side-citations}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only

\begin{document}

Hello, Tufte-Latex.

\lipsum[1]

Here is a paragraph in the middle of the page.
Donec varius orci egetrisus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum varius\cite{Sosic2018}, egetrisus\cite{Nguyen2015}, and congue eu, accumsan eleifend-\cite{Henderson2018} or diam\cite{Ranchod2015} rutrum.
Donec varius orci egetrisus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

\lipsum[2-3]

\bibliography{test}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\end{document}
```

```latex
@inproceedings{Sosic2018,
  title = {Inverse {{Reinforcement Learning}} via {{Nonparametric Subgoal Modeling}}},
  booktitle = {2018 {{AAAI Spring Symposium Series}}},
  author = {{\v S}o{\v s}i{\'c}, Adrian and Zoubir, Abdelhak M. and Koeppl, Heinz},
  year = {2018},
  pages = {344--350},
  publisher = {{AAAI Press, Palo Alto, California USA}},
  address = {{Palo Alto, California, USA}},
}

@inproceedings{Nguyen2015,
  title = {Inverse {{Reinforcement Learning}} with {{Locally Consistent Reward Functions}}},
  booktitle = {Advances in {{Neural Information Processing Systems}} 28},
  author = {Nguyen, Quoc Phong and Low, Bryan Kian Hsiang and Jaillet, Patrick},
  year = {2015},
  pages = {1747--1755},
  publisher = {{Curran Associates, Inc.}},
  address = {{Montr\'eal, Quebec, Canada}},
}

@inproceedings{Henderson2018,
  title = {{{OptionGAN}}: {{Learning Joint Reward}}-{{Policy Options Using Generative Adversarial Inverse Reinforcement Learning}}},
  shorttitle = {Optiongan},
  booktitle = {Thirty-{{Second AAAI Conference}} on {{Artificial Intelligence}}},
  author = {Henderson, Peter and Chang, Wei-Di and Bacon, Pierre-Luc and Meger, David and Pineau, Joelle and Precup, Doina},
  year = {2018},
  pages = {3199--3206},
  publisher = {{AAAI Press, Palo Alto, California USA}},
}

@inproceedings{Ranchod2015,
  title = {Nonparametric {{Bayesian Reward Segmentation}} for {{Skill Discovery Using Inverse Reinforcement Learning}}},
  booktitle = {2015 {{IEEE}}/{{RSJ International Conference}} on {{Intelligent Robots}} and {{Systems}} ({{IROS}})},
  author = {Ranchod, Pravesh and Rosman, Benjamin and Konidaris, George},
  year = {2015},
  pages = {471--477},
  publisher = {{IEEE}},
  address = {{Hamburg, Germany}},
  doi = {10.1109/IROS.2015.7353414},
  isbn = {978-1-4799-9994-1},
  language = {en}
}
```

---

1. Is it possible to configure `tufte-book` in such a way that the side-citations have a different format to the bibliography citations?
2. If not, how might I modify the `tufte-book` files to achieve this? Pointers to locations in the source code much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `AtEveryCitekey` to remove fields that you do not want from the side citations. For example:

```
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \clearfield{url}%
  \clearfield{address}%
  \clearfield{issn}%
  \clearfield{doi}%
}
```

To make citations shorter, it's easier to change the `citestyle` option of [biblatex](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book} % no bib

\usepackage[
  style=verbose, % style for the bibliography section
  citestyle=authortitle, % pick your style here for sidenotes
  autocite=footnote
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{myfile.bib}

\begin{document}

% your document ...
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```